# AngularJs view with Spring : Not showing

Tags: angularjs, spring, tomcat, model-view-controller

So I have a simple application AngularJs and Spring mvc. I have a controlller that mapped to the angularJs page and I have this code in a jsp page :

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>The name is <span ng-bind="person.lastName"></span></p>
{{ lastName }}
</div>

<script src="applications.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>
```

**application.js :**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

**controllers.js :**

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.firstName    = "John";
$scope.lastName= "Doe";
});
```

when I run this with *Pivotal* it dosn't run, but when I access the file directly within my browser it works like a charm, **Someone care to explain pls ?**

Thank you.
***EDIT***

**WebConfig.java :**

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
    .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Override 
public void configureDefaultServletHandling ( DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer ) 
{ 
    configurer.enable(); 
} 
}
```

**resources folder :**

[image: Resources folder]

**The URL :** http://localhost:8080/gestionprojet/Project/angularjs

**My Controller :**

```
@RequestMapping("/angularjs")
public String getAngularJs() {
    return "AngularJs";
}
```

Comment: what is the issue? what errors do you  see on console?

Comment: Nothing, the view is rendered and on the browser I see `{{lastname}} `

Comment: have you referenced angularjs in your application?

Comment: Check the network panel of your browser dev tools, and verify that all scripts are loaded correctly.

Comment: Yeah I did, as mentioned above, when I access the page directly from the browser it runs perfectly.

Comment: @JB Nizet  can you explain further?

Comment: Press F12 or Cmd-alt-i on Mac. Click the network tab. Refresh the page. Inspect all the HTTP requests that are traces in the network tab. Check that they're all successful.

Comment: They're not loaded!! Why?

Comment: Because they're not where they should be. What's the URL displayed in the address bar? Where are the JS files located in your war file? How have you configured Spring to serve static resources?

Comment: Yes I've checked I they're where it supposed to be. I'll update my answer with the code in a min.

Comment: @JB Nizet I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your files are under /WEB-INF/resources, but you have configured spring to load static resources from /resources. So they can't be served at all. The config should be

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
```

The URL of your page is

```
/gestionprojet/Project/angularjs
```

Your page tries to load the script using the relative path

```
applications.js
```

So the corresponding absolute path where the browser looks for the JS files is

```
/gestionprojet/Project/applications.js
```

which doesn't match with the URLs you choose to serve static resources from. Assuming `/gestionprojet` is the context path of the application, the absolute URL should be

```
/gestionprojet/resources/applications.js
```

So the source code in the JSP should thus be

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/applications.js"></script>
```